# How to pass environment variable to downstream job?

Tags: jenkins

I have an environment variable in a file in one job that I want to pass to another job.

In JobA,

[image]

In JobB:

[image]

But `JOB_A_VERSION` is not getting evaluated in the context of JobA.  It's just showing up as the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing parameters via a properties file works.

In jobA,

```
echo "MY_KEY=myvalue" > other_job_properties.txt
```

Trigger parametrized build on other projects -> Parameters from properties file -> other_job_properties.txt

Comment: maybe an old post but this saved me an headache: thanks man, it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Nevermind, this isnt the issue here. Try `$JOB_A_VERSION` or `${JOB_A_VERSION}` un unix-like systems. In case of windows batch you would have to use `%JOB_A_VERSION%`.

<s>You need to check *This build is parameterized* in the configuration of `JobB` and add the parameter you expect, aswell as how to interpret its content, i.e. you'd probably chose *Text parameter* here.</s>